# How can I compare time frequencies in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a fixed timeseries frequency, `'MS'`, against which I wish to compare data frequency in a Pandas DataFrame.

So, for example, I am given a DataFrame with a `date` column, and I can infer its time frequency using `pd.infer_freq(df['date'])`, which returns, for example `'H'`. That's great! I can now say that 'H' (hourly) is more frequent than 'MS' (month start). But given that I don't know what frequency the DataFrame will always have (I just provided 'H' as an example), how could I compare it to my fixed time frequency ('MS')?

What I tried was to put [all possible time frequencies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) in frequency order in a list / tuple, and then compare the index of 'MS' in the list to the index of the inferred frequency in the list. But that is prone to error, since if the DataFrame has an `'M'` (month end) frequency and in my list 'M' comes before 'MS', then it will be concluded that M is lower in frequency than MS, which is clearly false, as the two are equal frequencies.

Does Pandas even have a way to do time frequency comparison?

Thank you

Comment: How about complex patterns such as 3T < 100m?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a dictionary that maps all of the possible time frequencies to a number, where smaller numbers indicate it's a higher frequency. This allows you to map the same frequency, with a different description to the same number. Then just create a function to compare

```
dct = {'N': 0, 'U': 1, 'us': 1, 'L': 2, 'ms': 2}
```

Then you can use it to map the outputs to compare.

```
dct['us'] < dct['U']
#False

dct['us'] = dct['U']
#True
```

Comment: In lack of a Pandas-native method to do time frequency comparisons, this is what I've used, indeed.